# Little confusion in Priority Queue in C

Tags: c, data-structures, priority-queue

I've written the code like this:

```
ptr=front;
    while(ptr->link!=NULL && ptr->priority<itempriority ){
        ptr=ptr->link;
    }

    temp->link=ptr->link;
    ptr->link=temp;
    return front;
```

The above code didn't work.

```
  ptr=front;
        while(ptr->link!=NULL && ptr->link->priority<itempriority ){
            ptr=ptr->link;
        }

        temp->link=ptr->link;
        ptr->link=temp;
        return front;
```

This code worked perfectly.

I'm confused why my code was not working i.e. `ptr->priority<itempriority` ?

In short I want to know how `ptr->link->priority<itempriority` is working perfectly while `ptr->priority<itempriority` is not?

Comment: Can you show both the codes separately. It is difficult to understand what two codes are you comparing

Comment: Whenever you want to insert a node at a particular position you need a pointer to the previous node, so you need to make the decision to insert before you actually reach that position, which is why `ptr->link->priority` works and `ptr->priority` does not.

Comment: Ajay Brahmakshatriya  I've modified my query .. please check it

Comment: Gaurav Sehgal , would you please explain a bit more ?

Comment: Think about it. If you are comparing `ptr->priority` you have no reference to the node that came before. That's why you use `ptr->link->priority` because you are still on the current node and can insert between `current` and `link`. (the key to any problem like this is to draw a diagram of pointers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this

```
1 -> 2 -> 5 -> 8
```

and you want to insert `3` at correct position

```
while(ptr->link!=NULL && ptr->priority<itempriority ){
        ptr=ptr->link;
    }
```

At the end, `ptr` will be pointing to `5`.And finally you will have

```
1 -> 2 -> 5 -> 3 -> 8 //Wrong
```

The second version

```
while(ptr->link!=NULL && ptr->link->priority<itempriority ){
            ptr=ptr->link;
        }
```

At the end `ptr` will be `2`, and finally

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 8 //correct
```

Comment: Yes, that is another way to explain it without saying you have no reference to the previous node.

Comment: That was really helpful.